# Completely remove field from Content Type?

Tags: list, content-type, caml, reporting-services, delete

I recently tried to delete a Multi-line Text Field from a custom Content Type. I then attempted to delete this field, and re-create it as a Single line of text under the same field name.

After realizing that it wouldn't let me do this, I then used the below javascript command:

> `javascript:g_FieldName={};alert('Successfully cleared forbidden columns');`

This allowed me to create the field with the deleted column's name, just as I wanted.

However, now when I use a CAML query to pull this data into an SSRS report, it pulls the old fields data.

How can I completely remove a field from a Content Type? Is this possible using Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#get web and ct
$web = Get-SPWeb http://your/site/name
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["CT name"]

#get the column from the web
$spFieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink ($web.Fields["alias"])

#Remove the field from the ct and update
$ct.FieldLinks.Delete($spFieldLink.Id)
$ct.Update()

#dispose the web-object
$web.Dispose()
```